# React native javascript merge multi theme parameters

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, merge, javascript-objects

I have the following code that allows you to `merge` a theme, what I would like to do is to be able to pass an undefined number of themes.

How can I do?

Code:

```
  const mergeTheme = (baseTheme, theme, darkTheme) => ({
    ...Object.entries(baseTheme).reduce(
      (acc, [key, value]) => ({
        ...acc,
        [key]: {
          ...value,
          ...(theme[key] || {}),
          ...(darkTheme[key] || {}),
        },
      }),
      {},
    ),
  })
```

As I'd like it to be, the input parameters:

```
  const mergeTheme = (baseTheme, ...theme) => ({
    ...Object.entries(baseTheme).reduce(
      (acc, [key, value]) => ({
        ...acc,
        [key]: {
          ...value,

          <- Here

        },
      }),
      {},
    ),
  })
```

Comment: There are 2 functions with the same name `mergeTheme`. What does each one? Why does they have the same name?

Comment: The second function with the same name as the first and how I would like the function to become with the input parameters, but I get stuck in the part where it says here.  I thought you understood.

Comment: Edit your question clarifying that (in the text or as a comment in the code or splitting the code into 2 blocks, for example) so I can unvote it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.assign` to merge an array mapped from `themes` values of `key`:

```js
const mergeTheme = (baseTheme, ...themes) => ({
  ...Object.entries(baseTheme).reduce(
    (acc, [key, value]) => ({
      ...acc,
      [key]: {
        ...value,
        ...Object.assign({}, ...(themes.map(theme => theme[key])))
      },
    }),
    {},
  ),
});
```